# Rewrite custom post type URL parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite, parameter

I would like to change the following parameterized URL:

```
www.example.com/category/?keywords=&location=new-york&type=Wedding
```

in this way: (invert city > category)

```
www.example.com/category/wedding/new-york/
```

and delete: `Keywords=`, `&location=` and `&type=` from URL.

Can it be done somehow?

Comment: It is really hard without knowing how your CPT and custom taxonomy `category` is registered. The slug `category` is reserved by WordPress. I'd recommend you to change it to something else. Is `wedding` a term in your custom taxonomy and `new-york` a clild? Or they both are different taxonomies?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..
Category (I made a mistake in logging in)
Actually the URL is this:
www.example.com/page/?keywords=&location=new-york&type=wedding
where is it:
keyword is a simple parameter that retrieves from the search bar;
new-york is a taxonomy;
wedding is custom post type.
What I would like to do is:
delete: Keywords =, & location = and & type = from URL.
And reverse the order of CPT and taxonomy like so:
www.example.com/page/wedding/new-york/

Comment: Revesing the CTP slug and taxonomy slug will require you to understand how URL rewire works. Please check [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) to get started.